# What's "prime tickets"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> ...and my husband, Arthur, has just managed to get **prime tickets** through his connections at the Department of Magical Games and Sports.

As title, what's "prime tickets"? I haven't managed to find a good reference yet.

Comment: Any dictionary should supply a meaning of *prime* that makes sense here.

Comment: @choster, I got that, but I'm unsure if it's a special term in sports, since lots of simple words have special meanings in sports. Maybe, I should add my try in my question to indicate the research I made already.

Comment: @dan - Definitely should add that to your question. No such thing as too much research.

Comment: @J.R. Since there was an answer that already addressed it, it's not that necessary for me to repeat it in my question. Maybe, I can make a better question next time. Or we can close the question if it doesn't have any values.

Comment: I think it’s a good question. I just think it could be a better question with some additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're great tickets, meaning they're for great seats. See the following definition for "prime":

> [*attributive*] Of the best possible quality; excellent.
>
> *‘prime cuts of meat’*
>   <sub>[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prime)</sub>